# Is it true that $\|Du\|_{L^{2p}} \le C\|u\|_{L^\infty}^{1\over2} \|D^2u\|_{L^p}^{1\over 2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Is it true that$$\|Du\|_{L^{2p}} \le C\|u\|_{L^\infty}^{1\over2} \|D^2u\|_{L^p}^{1\over 2}$$for $1 \le p < \infty$ and all $u \in C_c^\infty(U)$?

Comment: prove it first for polynomials on $A \subset U$ and $\|.\|_{L^q(A)}$ ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a particular case of the Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality:
$$\|D^ju\|_{L^p} \le C\|u\|_{L^q}^{1-\alpha} \|D^m u\|_{L^r}^\alpha,$$
where
$$1\le r,q\le \infty, \quad \frac{1}{p} = \frac{j}{n} + \left(\frac{1}{r} - \frac{m}{n}\right)\alpha + \frac{1-\alpha}{q} \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{j}{m} \le \alpha \le 1.$$
There are two cases in which you need more restrictions, but they do not apply to yours. Take $j=1$, $m=2$, $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$, $p=2p$, $q=\infty$ and $r=p$.

You can see the original result in the paper [On elliptic partial differential equations](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/ASNSP/ASNSP_1959_3_13_2/ASNSP_1959_3_13_2_115_0/ASNSP_1959_3_13_2_115_0.pdf), by L. Nirenberg. As a reference for this and related results, I particularly like the book [Partial Differential Equations](https://books.google.es/books?id=Xnu0o_EJrCQC&printsec=frontcover&hl=es#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Lawrence C. Evans.